# Wordpress TwentyThirteen theme drop down menu stuck when "open in new tab" is selected

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, submenu

One of my users has an issue with one of my pages which is based on the twentythirteen wordpress theme. when he opens one of the drop down menus and then clicks right and chooses "open in new tab" in his browser, the dropdown menu does *not* disappear. it is *frozen* or *stuck*. You can move the mouse out of the drop down menu and the menu is still displayed which should not be the case. Only if you click somewhere else, the menu will disappear. Alternatively, the same happens if you click with the middle-button of your mouse (because this essentially is the same as "open in new tab").

The scenario can be replicated at the official twentythirteen demo page: https://twentythirteendemo.wordpress.com/
Just hover over *Blog archives* and click one of the appearing links with the middle mouse button (or right-click and then choose "open in new tab"). Then move the mouse away from the drop down menu and the menu will *not* disappear. see the following screenshot:

[image]

To me it seems, that the reason is, that the link is *active* because it was clicked and hence does not disappear. The issue is also present in newer wordpress themes.

Is there a solution for this? How can I prevent the drop down menu from getting stuck when I use "open in new tab" for one of the child elements? Or is this behavior expected? If yes, what should I tell the user of my site?

Answer (score 0):

This is intended for touch devices. You can comment out or remove this code twentythirteen/js/functions.js around line 59:

```
if ( 'ontouchstart' in window ) {
    menu.find( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' ).on( 'touchstart.twentythirteen', function( e ) {
        var el = $( this ).parent( 'li' );

        if ( ! el.hasClass( 'focus' ) ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            el.toggleClass( 'focus' );
            el.siblings( '.focus' ).removeClass( 'focus' );
        }
    } );
}

// Better focus for hidden submenu items for accessibility.
menu.find( 'a' ).on( 'focus.twentythirteen blur.twentythirteen', function() {
    $( this ).parents( '.menu-item, .page_item' ).toggleClass( 'focus' );
} );
```

Comment: thanks, will try it in the evening. just a question: what is the intention behind this for touch devices? so that sub-menues can be navigated more easily?

Comment: one more thing: i know, it's not best practice to directly change code in a parent theme. i have set up a child theme. how can I apply these changes in my child theme (no /js/function.js available).

Comment: On touch devices, you don't have a 'hover' so the first tap will act like a trigger to open the submenu.

Comment: On your child theme's functions.php dequeue the parent theme js
 wp_dequeue_script('twentythirteen-script');

Then copy the js file to your child theme, and enqueue it:
wp_enqueue_script( 'twentythirteen-child-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20160717', true );